# Light-weight drawing software that prints PDF with SVG quality

Tags: pdf, drawing, svg

After subscribing to Adobe Illustrator, I figured it was consuming 100% of my CPU. I am looking for a drawing software that can print PDF files with super good detailing, such as SVG.

**Is there any light drawing software that you guys know which can print PDF files the same quality as an SVG?**

I have used SketchBook and it is almost perfect, except by the fact it does not print the PDF with an SVG definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). It saves its files in SVG, and the PDF export is what you would expect.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Inkscape unfortunately does not support multiple pages. Would you have any other recommendation?

Comment: [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) is another one, but it seems it's not as straightforward to export to SVG. I'm not sure there are many that support multiple pages, given that you can just easily open a new document for each page.

Comment: Krita can only export to SVG as far as I know. I can maybe use SVG to PDF conversion methods but that would be a lot of work to do. Inkscape has proven to me to be very good. Is there any other application you know that can export to PDF like Inkscape?

Comment: Right, you wanted to export to PDF, I mixed that up. Funnily, Krita doesn't actually have a PDF export option, nor a print option as far as I can see. There's also [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) but I have no experience with that at all. That's about all I know.